# About Dart async/await.I used a piece of code to test,But the print result is not as expected

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

```dart
void main() {
  methodA();
  methodB();
  methodC('main');
  methodD();
}

methodA(){
  print('A');
}

methodB() async {
  print('B start');
  await methodC('B');
  print('B end');
}

methodC(String from) async {
  print('C start from $from');
  Future((){                
    print('C running Future from $from');
  }).then((_){
    print('C end of Future from $from');
  });
  print('C end from $from');
}

methodD(){
  print('D');
}
```

The print results are as follows:

```
A
B start
C start from B
C end from B
C start from main
C end from main
D
B end
C running Future from B
C end of Future from B
C running Future from main
C end of Future from main
```

What I don't understand is why `C start from main` and `C end from main` prints before `B end`??
That is why `print('B end')` has not been executed yet, `methodC('main')` has already been executed.
I thought I understood `async/await` ,but until I came across this code.And I hope to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is:

- The runtime system calls `main`.
- `main` calls `methodA`.
- `methodA` prints **"A"**.
- `methodA` returns.
- `main` calls `methodB`.
- `methodB` prints **"B start"**.
- `methodB` calls `methodC("B")`.
- `methodC` prints **"C start from B"**.
- `methodC` creates a future, *f1*, using the `Future` constructor. This schedules a *timer* *t1*.
- `methodC` calls `then` on *f1* which adds a listener on *f1* and returns a future *g1*. (This future is ignored).
- `methodC` prints **"C end from B"**.
- `methodC`, because it's `async`, returns a future, *h1*, and schedules a microtask *m1* to complete that future with `null`.
- `methodB` awaits for *h1*.
- `methodB`, because it's async, returns a future *k*. (This future is ignored).
- `main` calls `methodC("main")`.
- `methodC` prints **"C start from main"**.
- `methodC` creates a future, *f2*, using the `Future` constructor. This schedules a *timer* *t2*.
- `methodC` calls `then` on *f2* which adds a listener on *f2* and returns a future *g2*. This future is ignored.
- `methodC` prints **"C end from main"**.
- `methodC`, because it's `async`, returns a future, *h2*, and schedules a microtask *m2* to complete that future with `null`. (The future is ignored).
- `main` calls `methodD`.
- `methodD` prints **"D"**.
- `methodD` returns.
- `main` returns.
- The microtask loop runs microtask *m1*, which completes future *h1* with null.
- `methodB` completes its `await` expression because *h1* has completed.
- `methodB` prints **"B end"**.
- `methodB` completes future *k* with `null`. Nobody is listening for that.
- The microtask loop runs microtask *m2*, which completes future h2 with null. Nobody is listenting for that.
- The microtask queue is now empty.
- The event loop runs timer *t1*, which

  - prints **"C running Future from B"**.
  - completes the *f1* future with `null`.
  - invokes the `then` listener on *f1* and.
  - prints **"C end of Future from B"**.
  - completes the *g1* future with `null. Nobody is listening.
- The event loop runs timer *t2*, which

  - prints **"C running Future from main"**.
  - completes the *f1* future with `null`.
  - invokes the `then` listener on *f1* and.
  - prints **"C end of Future from main"**.
  - completes the *g1* future with `null. Nobody is listening.
- The event and microtask queues are now empty, and the program exits.

Comment: You are really nice！You are really nice！ Thank you very much Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When you use await keyword then the further statements will not get executed until the current subroutine/statement flow gets executed.

For Ex:

```
methodB() async {
  print('B start');
  await methodC('B');
  print('B end');
}
```

Here, after **print('B start')** you called **methodC('B')** with await keyword. So, now **print('B end')** will get executed after all the statements and method of the **methodC('B')** gets executed. Till then **print('B end')** statement will wait for the execution of the **methodC('B')**

Comment: I understand what you are saying here。`methodB()` is before `methodC('main')` in the `main()`.  why `print('B end')` has not been executed yet, `methodC('main')` has already been executed.